# Azure Blob Storage security

Tags: security, azure, ftp, blob, storage

I want to mimic the features of a secure FTP Server, such that the end user would have to present credentials or a token before the end user can download a file.

How can this be accomplished using blob storage? Shared Access Signatures does not work, as once you have the URL you have access to the file?
I want a feature such that the user either enters his/her credentials or presents token before the download. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended pattern is to write your own service that authenticates the user, checks if they're authorized for the requested resource, and then returns either:

the requested resource:
[image]

or a Shared Access Signature for the requested resource:
[image]

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/#when-should-you-use-a-shared-access-signature